# Google Cloud Pub/Sub retries the message delivery if it does not get a response in 30 seconds. Intended?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using a Java 8 servlet as a Cloud Pub/Sub push endpoint.
On my push endpoint I have a long-running blocking operation, that sometimes runs for over a minute.
After the operation is done, I return a `200` response, acking the message.

If I return a `500` server error, the message is retried, which is expected.

Note that I create my subscription with a maximum allowed deadline ack period of 600 seconds.

What I have noticed is that if my long-running operation runs for over 30 seconds, the message is also retried. Seems like the HTTP connection that is used for push delivery does not live for over 30 seconds or something.

Is this intended? Is it configurable somehow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you have a support package you should consider creating a support ticket as this seems to be an unexpected behaviour from Pub/Sub. In case you don’t have it, refer to the [Google Issue Tracker][1] and create an issue so that your error can be tracked. You will find the steps to create an issue [here][2].

---------------
[1]: https://issuetracker.google.com
[2]: https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui

Answer (score 1):

For push subscriptions, Cloud Pub/Sub does not send a negative acknowledgment (sometimes known as a nack). If your webhook does not return a success code within the acknowledgment deadline, Cloud Pub/Sub retries delivery until the message expires after the subscription's message retention period. You can configure a default acknowledgment deadline for push subscriptions when you [create the push subscription](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/subscription/create) (select push subscription and set **Acknowledgement deadline**).

Note that, unlike for pull subscriptions, the deadline cannot be extended for individual messages. The deadline is effectively the amount of time the endpoint has to respond to the push request.

Comment: I've forgot to mention that the ack deadline period for my subscription is set to 600 seconds. Edited my original question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is expected.
Pubsub guarantee at-least one time delivery until you acknowledge the message.

You can add delay in Push subscription by adding setting in Subsccription.

```
   Go To subscription -> Edit ->Acknowledgement deadline -> 
   set values from 10 Seconds to 600 Seconds(10 Minutes).
```

[image]